# How to Get Rid of white grubs?

Tags: vegetables, insects, organic, eggplant

I noticed that I have grubs in my garden. Is there anything Organic that I can use to get rid of them?
These little things totally destroy my tomato and pepper plants.

[image]

Comment: I guest this is a good reason why not to solely rely on google. According to the blog that I read, weevil has a black head and while body in the early stages. That why I thought it was weevil.

Comment: Not an unreasonable description, but if you look close at this guy, he most likely has 4-6 legs near the front half, weevils are legless. Also, as @Escoce pointed out, weevils usually show up in and feed on stored grains, not in soil. Grubs are more likely soil pests, they feed on roots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can get one out of the soil and inspect it thoroughly, you should be able to decide exactly what type of grub it is. I don't know where you are in the world, so can't hazard a guess at whether its Japanese Beetle larvae or not - the link below has a picture of 3 different grubs which look remarkably similar, and also lists organic methods for attempting to deal with them.

http://www.toxicfreenc.org/organicgardening/japanese_beetles.html#.VgZ3MG4Tbcs

In the UK, we have a nematode solution for chafer grubs, but not for Japanese Beetle - we don't yet have those here fortunately, so what you can find to treat any of them with is, to some extent, dependent on where you live.